# MySQL Database Connection in Pentaho

Tags: mysql-workbench, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to create a new connection in pentaho to connect mysql database. And I am getting an below error.

Pentaho community edition V6.1
Connector : mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar

> Error connecting to database [Reports] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
>   Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection timed out

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection timed out

Comment: Have you successfully connected before to a mysql database or this is the first-ever attempt? If the latter is true, have you followed the instructions about placing the connector .jar? If the latter is true, have you added all required information to the connection (a screenshot from spoon would be helpful). Connecting to a db is fairly straightforward and the error you get is generic so before speculating, we need to make sure that the fundamentals are done correctly.

Comment: you are using mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar file.. which is outdated for pdi 6.1.download the newer version of jdbc connector your problem will be resolved.